# Accessing child control of a gridview from Java

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, gridview

The below code works, I'm just curious if there is a dynamic way to pass the generated
 GridLeft__ctl1_GridViewLeftSearch ID into the javascript function.

pseudo code -

```
  <HeaderTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="GridViewLeftTextBox" Width="80%" runat="server"
onKeyPress="javascript:SearchLeft(event);"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="GridViewLeftSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" 
OnClick="onSearchLeftGrid" Text="Search Patients" Font-Size="Small">
</asp:Button>
      </HeaderTemplate>
```

Is their a way to access The GridViewLeftSearch Button inside this Javascript function without hard coding it?

```
function SearchLeft(e) {

          var t = document.getElementById("GridLeft__ctl1_GridViewLeftSearch");
                       if (t != null) {
                           t.click();
                       }


               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
function SearchLeft(e) {

      var t = document.getElementById("<%= GridViewLeftSearch.ClientID %>");
                   if (t != null) {
                       t.click();
                   }


           }
```